# List View not sorting Date Column in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, date-sorting

I Want to sort list view in wpf using date column.But below code is sorting string and not date.
I have bind the data table to the list view.
Here is my code.

```
<ListView.View>
<GridView x:Name="gvDetails" >
<GridViewColumn  Header="Header1"       Width="130"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}" />
<GridViewColumn  Header="Header2"        Width="120"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}"  />
<GridViewColumn  Header="Header3"         Width="120"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}"  />
<GridViewColumn   Header="DateOfEnquiry"   Width="120"     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfEnquiry}" />
</GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Sorting Code:

```
 ICollectionView dataView =
               CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstvwDetails.ItemsSource);
            if (dataView != null)
            {
                dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("DateOfEnquiry", direction);

                dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            }
```

But this is not sorting the listview date column datewise but sorting as string only.
Please advise.

Comment: What it the type of `DateOfEnquiry`? Is it `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample will help you:

```
string propertyName = "DateOfEnquiry";

ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstvwDetails.ItemsSource);
ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

if (dataView.SortDescriptions.Count > 0 && dataView.SortDescriptions[0].PropertyName == propertyName)
{
    if (dataView.SortDescriptions[0].Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending) direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
    else direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
}
dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, direction));
```